# Qt Installer Framework - load binary automatically once installation is finished

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I want to load the binary automatically once installation is completed using Qt Installation framework. How this can be achieved?

I am trying to edit this script and added component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/DistributionKit/Abc.sh"); But its not loading the script automatically. What i am missing ?

```js
function Component()
{
    installer.installationFinished.connect(this, Component.prototype.installationFinishedPageIsShown);
    installer.finishButtonClicked.connect(this, Component.prototype.installationFinished);

}


Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    component.createOperations();
}

Component.prototype.installationFinishedPageIsShown = function()
{
    try {
        if (installer.isInstaller() && installer.status == QInstaller.Success) {
            installer.addWizardPageItem( component, "ReadMeCheckBoxForm", QInstaller.InstallationFinished );
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

Component.prototype.installationFinished = function()
{
    try {
        if (installer.isInstaller() && installer.status == QInstaller.Success) {
            var isReadMeCheckBoxChecked = component.userInterface( "ReadMeCheckBoxForm" ).readMeCheckBox.checked;
            if (isReadMeCheckBoxChecked) {
                //QDesktopServices.openUrl("file:///" + installer.value("TargetDir") + "/Abc.sh");
  component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/DistributionKit/Abc.sh");
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I always use what you have as a comment in your code: `QDesktopServices.openUrl("file:///....");` with .... the absolute path of your file. Exactly as you have it commented out in your example.

Comment: But i dont want to load any .txt file. I want to load a binary (os : linux)

Comment: If you want to start a standalone program. You can try with [`installer.executeDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#executeDetached-method)

Answer (score 0):

Qt installer framework has an [`executeDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#executeDetached-method) function in the installer. I believe this is what you need to use to launch your program. In this case, your script would look like (only adding the affected function):

```
Component.prototype.installationFinished = function()
{
    try {
        if (installer.isInstaller() && installer.status == QInstaller.Success) {
            var isReadMeCheckBoxChecked = component.userInterface( "ReadMeCheckBoxForm" ).readMeCheckBox.checked;
            if (isReadMeCheckBoxChecked) {
                installer.exectueDetached("bash", installer.value("TargetDir") + "/Abc.sh");
                component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/DistributionKit/Abc.sh");
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Note that you actually need to run "bash" as `executeDetached` and pass your script as an argument to the bash. If you were running an executable you would not have "bash" in the `exectueDetached` command.

*Note that I did not add `"/DistributionKint/"` in the `exectueDetached`. This is because in the commented line in your original question `Abc.sh` was directly under `@TargetDir@`. Obviously, you need to pass the `installer.executeDetached` the right path to your sh script.

Comment: How to define the correct path of the script? Is there any specific syntax to define the path? Because my script is in the path as shown : /home/../../packages/../data/DistributionKit. So how i need to specify this path? Also do i need component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/DistributionKit/Abc.sh"); if i am using installer.exectueDetached() ??

Comment: At some point before running `binarycreator` you will copy your `Abc.sh` script into your package data folder. Everything in that folder will be copied during installation into  `TargetDir`. Therefore, the path of your `Abc.sh` script will be `TargetDir` + relative path to ' Abc.sh` within your package data folder.

Comment: Regarding the create shortcut part, you do not need it unless you do want to create a shortcut to your `Abc.sh` script. `executeDetached` will work regardless of your shortcut being created or not.

Comment: If you think this is a good answer please mark it as accepted and upvote. Otherwise please tell me more about your problem to help you fix it.

Comment: Getting error as shown : TypeError: Property 'exectueDetached' of object QInstaller::PackageManagerCore(0x319ed70) is not a function

Comment: Can you share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces this error?